# split item to rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the data in dataframes like below. 
I want to split the item into same number of rows

```
>>> df
idx  a  
0  3  
1  5  
2  4
```

from above dataframe, I want the below as

```
>>> df
idx  a  
0  1  
1  2  
2  3
3  1
4  2
5  3
6  4
7  5
8  1
9  2
10  3
11  4
```

I tried several ways, but no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Fun way

```
df.a.map(range).explode()+1 # may add reset_index(), however, I think keep the original index is good, and help us convert back.
Out[158]: 
idx
0    1
0    2
0    3
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    5
2    1
2    2
2    3
2    4
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: You might wanna `reset_index` as the OP needs unique index @YOBEN_S

Comment: @VishnudevV sure I will

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way with [`series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) +`Groupby. cumcount`  assuming `idx` is the index- if not `df.set_index('idx')['a']..rest of the code..`

```
(df['a'].repeat(df['a']).groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
        .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('idx'))
```

---

```
idx

0     1
1     2
2     3
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     1
9     2
10    3
11    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a numpy based one:

```
a = (np.arange(df.a.max())+1)
m = a <= df.a.values[:,None]
df = pd.DataFrame(m.cumsum(1)[m], columns=['a'])
```

---

```
print(df)

    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   5
8   1
9   2
10  3
11  4
```

Answer (score 5):

#### List Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [x + 1 for y in df['a'] for x in range(y)]})

    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   5
8   1
9   2
10  3
11  4
```